# Why I get 400 error for wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to make a shortcode that adds the woocommerce item selected from the dropdown menu to the cart if I click on "Pay" button, but I keep getting a 400 error code.

I added this to my theme's function.php:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_add_product_to_cart', 'add_product_to_cart_callback' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_add_product_to_cart', 'add_product_to_cart_callback' );

function add_product_to_cart_callback() {
    $product_id = isset( $_POST['product_id'] ) ? intval( $_POST['product_id'] ) : '';
    if ( WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id ) ) {
        echo 'success';
    } else {
        echo 'error';
    }
    die();
}
```

Then tried to call that function:

```
function test_function() {
    ob_start();
    ?>
    <div class="woocommerce">
        <?php
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
        );
        $products = new WP_Query($args);
        ?>
        <select name="product_id" id="product-select">
            <?php while ($products->have_posts()) : $products->the_post(); ?>
                <option value="<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></option>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </select>
        <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

        <button type="button" class="button alt" id="add-to-cart"><?php _e('Pay', 'woocommerce'); ?></button>
    </div>

    <script>
    const addToCartButton = document.getElementById('add-to-cart');
    const productSelect = document.getElementById('product-select');
    addToCartButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
        const productId = productSelect.value;
        console.log(productId);
            if (productId) {
                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
                    data: {
                        'action': 'wp_ajax_add_product_to_cart', //here I call the function
                        'product_id': productId
                    },
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(response) {
                    window.location.href = '<?php echo wc_get_cart_url(); ?>';
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    </script>
<?php
    return ob_get_clean();
    }
add_shortcode('test', 'test_function');
```